# PUT file with AWS presignedURL

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm creating presigned URL with aws-sdk-php for uploading files to S3 bucket. URLs for GET are working.

Here is the code

```
$client = S3Client::factory(array('region' => 'eu-west-1','key' => 'xxx','secret' => 'xxx',));

//option 1
$command = $client->getCommand('PutObject', array(
    'Bucket' => 'myBucket',
    'Key' => 'testing/signedPHP1_'.time(),
    'ContentType' => 'image/jpeg',
    'Body' => 'dump' //it's mandatory
));
$signedUrl = $command->createPresignedUrl('+5 minutes');
$signedUrl .= '&Content-Type=image%2Fjpeg';
echo("\n\nThe URL is: ". $signedUrl . "\n");
echo("Now run from console for upload:\ncurl -v -H \"Content-Type: image/jpeg\" -T /tmp/temp.jpg '" . $signedUrl . "'");

//option 2
$request = $client->put('myBucket/testing/signedPHP2_'.time());
$signedUrl = $client->createPresignedUrl($request, '+5 minutes');
$signedUrl .= '&Content-Type=image%2Fjpeg';
echo("\n\nThe URL is: ". $signedUrl . "\n");
echo("Now run from console for upload:\ncurl -v -H \"Content-Type: image/jpeg\" -T /tmp/temp.jpg '" . $signedUrl . "'");

//GET which works
$request = $client->get('myBucket/testing/existingFile.txt');
$signedUrl = $client->createPresignedUrl($request, '+5 minutes');
echo("\n\nThe URL is: ". $signedUrl . "\n");
echo("Now run:\ncurl '" . $signedUrl . "'");

//GET which works
$command = $client->getCommand('GetObject', array('Bucket' => 'myBucket','Key' => 'upload/data.txt'));
$signedUrl = $command->createPresignedUrl('+5 minutes');
echo("\n\nThe URL is: ". $signedUrl . "\n");
echo("Now run:\ncurl '" . $signedUrl . "'");
```

When trying to use curl command I'm getting and error
**SignatureDoesNotMatch** with message **The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method**.

The similar code in aws-sdk for Javascript is working

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.update({ accessKeyId: 'xxx', secretAccessKey: 'xxx', region: 'eu-west-1' });
var s3 = new AWS.S3();
var params = {
    Bucket: 'myBucket',
    Key: 'testing/preSignedURLnodeJS_' + (+new Date),
    ContentType: 'image/jpeg',
    Expires: 60 * 5
};
s3.getSignedUrl('putObject', params, function(err, url) {
    console.log('The URL is: ', url);
    console.log('Now run from console for upload:\n\ncurl -v -H "Content-Type: image/jpeg" -T /tmp/temp.jpg \'' + url + '\'');
});
```

Already done a lot of researching but no results. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On Github I got an answer from SDK developer and it says

```
$command = $client->getCommand('PutObject', array(
    'Bucket' => 'myBucket',
    'Key' => 'testing/signedPHP1_'.time(),
    'ContentType' => 'image/jpeg',
    'Body'        => '',
    'ContentMD5'  => false
));
```

Reference: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php/issues/239

Comment: I'm confused.. bennie j seems to have given you this answer below, yet you have provided your own answer rather than accept his? Seems like bad form...

Comment: I know that you can use putObject. But if need to allow third party to upload to your private bucket, then creating presigned URL is the right way.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

First, create the presigned URLs

```
<?php 
/**
 *  getDocumentUploadUrls
 *
 *  creates a list of url so you can upload multiple files per
 *  document. After uploading the files it is requires for you
 *  to confirm the uploads.
 *
 *  @param Int $documentId the document id
 *  @param Int $count the amount of files you want to upload for this document
 *
 *  @return Array list of URLs to use with PUT request to upload files to s3.
 */
public function getDocumentUploadUrls(Int $documentId, Int $count = 1): Array
{
    $awsService = $this->getService('aws');

    $s3Client = $awsService->getSdk()->createS3();

    $urls = array_fill(1, $count, null);

    $bucket = 'yourbucket';

    $result = [];

    $expire = '+20 minutes';

    for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
        $fileCount = $i + 1;

        $key = "{$documentId}/{$fileCount}";

        $cmd = $s3Client->getCommand('PutObject', [
            'Bucket' => $bucket,
            'Key'    => $key
        ]);

        $request = $s3Client->createPresignedRequest($cmd, $expire);

        $result[] = [
            'url' => (string) $request->getUri(),
            'reference' => "{$bucket}/{$key}"
        ];
    }

    return $result;
}
```

The result may look similar to this:

```
$result = [
    0 => [
        'url' => 'AwsS3://put/uri',
        'reference' => 'docId/count'
    ]
];
```

Now, to upload with php cURL:

```
if ($request->isPost()) {
        $files = $request->getFiles()->toArray();

        $files = reset($files);

        $data = $request->getPost();

        $docId = $data['documentId']; // get this from your frontend POST params

        $docCount = count($files);

        try {
            $endpoints = $this->getDocumentUploadUrls($userId, $docId, $docCount);

            $uploadInfo = $this->uploadDocuments($endpoints, $files);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            // handle exception
        }
}

public function uploadDocuments(Array $endpoints, Array $files)
{
    $info = [];

    foreach ($files as $index => $file) {
        $url = $endpoints[$index]['url']; // the no. of files must match the number of endpoints for this to work

        $type = isset($file['type']) ? $file['type'] : 'application/octet-stream';

        $headers = [
            "Content-Type: $type",
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *',
        ];

        $ch = curl_init($url);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $file);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

        $response = curl_exec($ch);

        if (curl_errno($ch)) {
            throw new \Exception(curl_error($ch));
        }

        curl_close($ch);

        $info[] = [
            'headers' => $headers,
            'response' => $response
        ];
    }

    return $info;
}
```

Comment: This is the solution. 
Thanks @Gus

Answer (score -1):

If you are using the sdk why not use the putObject command, rather than creating a put request yourself. This will take care of the signedUrl for you.

```
$result = $client->putObject(array(
    'Bucket'     => $bucket,
    'Key'        => 'data_from_file.txt',
    'SourceFile' => $pathToFile
));
```

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/latest/class-Aws.S3.S3Client.html#_putObject

If you don't want that, you need to look at the body of your put command, this should be the contents of the file you are uploading, not just a random string 'dump'.

Run wireshark on the machine running the command and you will see the body of the request curl is making is the contents of the file.

Comment: That is not a issue! I would like to create presigned URL, send it to third party do he can upload file to my bucket without knowing access/secret key.